# Как сбросить пароль на Ubuntu, если у меня только один пользователь

Tags: ubuntu

Всем привет! Мне нужно использовать sudo, но система просит пароль, которого я не знаю, при этом у меня один пользователь, сбросить не получается :(

Я использую Ubuntu LTS 20.04.6

Comment: как же вы логинитесь, если пароль не знаете?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin автологин *ванга.жпг*

Comment: Если пароля в принципе нет, то установите его командой `passwd`. Если пароль есть и вы его забыли, то тогда наверное сбрасывайте пароль через LiveCD/LiveUSB или через `init=/bin/bash` или типа того